# Personal Macro Workbook Projects Still Visible, Code Randomly Went Missing

Tags: excel, vba

I could only find questions about the personal macro workbook disappearing, however, I can locate and open mine just fine (so it seems), only difference is I can see all of the different modules I have created over time, but I can't open any of them. They don't appear in the macro list either.

Lastly, I noticed the macro is now named "PERSONALxlsb.XLSB" when before it was "PERSONAL.xlsb." I don't know how that happened or if its related.

How can I get all of my personal macro workbook code back?! Please help! :)

Comment: Where can you see them?

Comment: When I launch the VBA editor you can see the modules on the left panel but when you double click none of the subs within the module open. When I view macros within a worksheet, the subs dont show there either. It can't tell if somehow it's locked, or disabled (although I checked to make sure macros were turned on)or if they are just gone.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the macro so it is highlighted then going File->Export to see if you can save the .bas file anywhere else? If that works try Importing back into a new workbook.

Comment: I get an error that says, "file not found. Check the Name" when I try to import into a new XLSB file.

Comment: Ok were you able to save the .bas files in another folder? If so maybe create a copy of one and rename the filename so ends .txt and open in notepad to see if the code is still there. Also you could create a copy of the Personal file and again rename it so it is Personal.zip then extract it and see if that fixes the problem?